# Squarefree numbers

Tags: number-theory

From the [Wolfram MathWorld page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Squarefree.html) on squarefree numbers,

> "There is no known polynomial time algorithm for recognizing squarefree integers or for computing the squarefree part of an integer."

Wolfram MathWorld says that

> "This problem is an important unsolved problem in number theory because computing the ring of integers of an algebraic number field is reducible to computing the squarefree part of an integer."

Would there be any other applications for an algorithm that recognizes squarefree integers?

Comment: try this.  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064068/can-the-sum-of-two-squares-be-used-to-determine-if-a-number-is-square-free

Comment: See this [Answer by Dietrich Burde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088146/how-to-detect-square-free-numbers/4088174?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#4088174) with regard to *recognizing* squarefree integers.  The article linked there was published a little over a year after this Question was posted.

Comment: @hardmath thank you

Comment: Here's a link to arXiv.org version of [Detecting Squarefree Numbers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6937) by Booker et al (Feb. 2015, Duke Math J.).  The one in the other Answer leads to a paywalled site.

Comment: @hardmath perfect! thank you