# How to detect square free numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

This may seem like a weird question, but how to find the numbers with non-exponential prime factors i.e. numbers which specifically have primes that occur only once in its prime-factorization.
For eg: $15=3×5$,   $70=2×5×7$. So, 15 and 70 are such numbers which have prime-factors that occur only once in its prime-factorization.

$28=7×4$. In its prime-factorization = $7×2×2$
So, 28 is NOT a number which has prime-factors that occur only once.

So, is there any way to find such numbers??

Thank you.

Comment: "non-exponential" is bad terminology. You should say repeated prime factors. They are called square-free numbers. You can get them by multiplying different prime factors (ex:2*3*5*7*11*13).

Comment: The official term is "square-free" (as none of their factors [except $1$] can be a square).  What do you mean "how do you find them"?  You multiply together one or more distinct primes and ... there they are....

Comment: I really have no idea what you mean "how to find them".  You can make a list of them.  If $p_i$ are all the primes in order then we can make exhaustive systematic list.  $2,3,2\cdot 3,5,2\cdot 5,3\cdot 5, 2\cdot 3\cdot 5, 7, 2\cdot 7... etc$.  We can describe this as every time we come to a new prime multiply that prime by all the terms on our list so for..... but *serious* what *on earth* do you mean how do you find them?  They are *right* there!  What's to be found?

Comment: You can write every positive integer in a prime factorization as $\prod p_i^{k_i}$ where $p_i$ is a prime and $k_i$ is a positive integer.  So $28 = 2^2 \cdot 7$. The square free one are those where all the powers are just one.  $14 = 2\times 7$ is on.  Given any number such as $50,400=2^53^25^27$ and "squish it" to $2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot7 =210$.  And if you *have* a number and want to *see* if it square free.... well, just prime factor it and *look* if it is.

Comment: @DietrichBurde in your edit, are *you* sure the OP was asking about how to detect if a given number were square-free rather than how to find a square-free number?

Comment: @fleablood To be honest, I am not sure. I thought this would make more sense, since writing down square free numbers is "trivial".

Comment: There is no efficient algorithm known to decide whether a given number is squarefree.

Answer (score 3):

There is an algorithm for "detecting square free numbers". See for example the [article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-164/issue-2/Detecting-squarefree-numbers/10.1215/00127094-2856619.short) by Andrew R. Booker, Ghaith A. Hiary, Jon P. Keating:

"We present an algorithm, based on the explicit formula for
$L$-functions and conditional on the generalized Riemann hypothesis, for proving that a given integer is squarefree with little or no knowledge of its factorization. We analyze the algorithm both theoretically and practically and use it to prove that several RSA challenge numbers are not squarefull."

Comment: +1, this is a really excellent interpretation of and answer to a very vague question.